# Как сделать что б после выполнения цикла do while производилось вычисление минимального числа и максимального?

Tags: c

Есть код но не могу никак вывести максимальное значение.

Сам код:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ukr");

    float x, y, min, max;
    max = min = x;


    do
    {
        printf("Введите x ");
        scanf_s("%f", &x);

        if ((x == -7) || (x == 0) || (x == 7))
        {
            printf("Функция не найдена!\n");
            continue;
        }
        else if ((x>-3) && (x<3))
        {
            printf("x больше -3 i меньше 3! y=x!", '/n');
            y = x;
        }
        else if (x<-3)
        {
            printf("x меньше -3! y=(x^2-3*x+2)/x", '/n');
            y = ((powf(x, 2) - 3 * x + 2) / x);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("x больше 3! y=x^3", '/n');
            y = (powf(x, 3));
        }
        printf("\ny=%f\n", y);
    } while (y>0);
    if (y < min)
        min = y;
    else if (y > max)
        max = y;
    printf("Минимальное число = %f", min, '/n');
    printf("Максимальное число = %f", max);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Совершенно не понятно, минимум и максимум чего вы ищете? Тем более что обе переменных min и max не были инициализированы.

Answer (score 1):

`max = min = x;` - эта строка задает начальные значения, но через переменную x, которая не инициализирована и хранит какой-то мусор. Это первое.
Условия на min и max у вас за телом цикла, в результате никакого поиска не будет и условия сработают только для последнего y.
Вам пора изучать отладчик чтобы не задавать таких вопросов.